# What Kind of adapter can I use for a 2.5" SSD into a Dell PowerEdge R320?

Tags: dell-poweredge, ssd

I'd purchased a a caddy like this: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00BR0L3U8/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BR0L3U8) assuming I would be able to front load this into the R320, but when I opened the front, I found that this machine didn't accommodate this type of caddy. Here is the server in question, note the empty bay on the right. I pulled out the empty tray, which is in the photo below this...

[image]

On the left is 2.5 SSD with the tray I purchased (which doesn't fit). Next to it is the empty tray from the system...

[image]

What do I need to make the 2.5" drive work in this machine? I'm doing this as free favor for a client and don't have the budget to buy an expensive solution... is there some sort of adapter that will fit in the blank?

Comment: I am going to do this in the coming months as well, and am thinking of trying this out: http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-Dell-R710-T710-3-5-to-2-5-HDD-Bracket-Caddy-9W8C4-/290710330355 - not posting as an answer because I can't confirm that it works.

Comment: @Mark, I cross posted on a Dell forum and someone suggested this: http://www.amazon.com/Drive-Caddy-Adapter-Poweredge-Servers/dp/B009DZSMYO I'm that familiar with this form factor server, but it does look like it will work...

Comment: That looks like the best of both worlds - the same adapter that's on ebay inside a full caddy.

Comment: @Kendor I've used that caddy before to good effect.